# Create and combine several images into a single image for my react native App

Tags: reactjs, react-native, image

I'm currently working on a react native application, and for one of my features I'll need to create an image from a selection of images chosen by the user. How do I go about generating such an image and storing it in firebase?
Is it possible to do this directly in my application, or would I need to set up an external service for performance reasons?  I imagine there are already existing tools for doing this sort of thing, is there one you'd recommend?

Each of the child images to be integrated belongs to a category and would have a well-defined placement in the parent image. For example, if my first child image belongs to category A, then it must be placed at the top left of the parent image and occupy 1/2 of the total height. If the second child image belongs to category B, then it must be placed to the right of the parent image and occupy the full height, etc. etc.
To respect this, I imagine I'd have to enter an x and y position in my parent image for each of my sub-images.